# auto variable declaration without definition

Tags: c++, auto

I was wondering if there's an elegant solution for the following issue:

Let's say I'd like to have a variable holding a value with a pretty complex type and would the compiler to automatically infer it's type, but declare first and give value later in the code because of initialization in an if statement.

For example:

```
{
  auto a;
  if (some predicate)
      a = init_a(1);
  else
      a = init_a(2);
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't compile, but the I think that the compiler has all the information it needs to infer the type.

If 'a' was just an int, this was not a problem, but if the type is a complex template, I don't want to have to write it (or in some cases even know it).
Also, i wouldn't want to call the default constructor of a and then write over it.

Possible solutions:

1. Template the type of 'a'.
2. initialize 'a' using a lambda and move the predicate into the lambda.
3. Just write the type of 'a' instead auto.
4. Use a void pointer/shared_ptr and then init 'a' on the heap.

Each of these has its own drawbacks.

Is there a more elegant solution for it?

Comment: Yes, use a function that `return`s either version of `a`, and then do `auto a = that_function()` at the current place. Or as said, a ternary operator should suffice in simple cases.

Comment: `auto a = some predicate ? init_a(1) : init_a(2);`?

Comment: Using the ternary operator is probably best; if you want to be generic and want `a` declared first, you could do `decltype(init_a(1)) a;` (or an optional of that, which is similar to but better than your 4 since it would use stack storage), but use the ternary.

Comment: If you don't want to write out a complex template instantiation, have you considered defining a type alias?

Answer (score 11):

The compiler doesn't have infinite lookahead what is happening further on in the code. It only knows what's happening at the current statement. Therefore it can't deduce any types without an initializer.

If you don't know the return-type of `init_a` then you could use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
decltype(init_a(1)) a;
```

You can also use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) call to initialize the variable:

```
auto a = [ /* Captures needed for the condition... */ ]()
{
    if (some_condition)
        return init_a(1);
    else
        return init_a(2);
}();  // Call the lambda immediately
```

Or, as mentioned in many comments, use the ternary conditional expression:

```
auto a = some_condition ? init_a(1) : init_a(2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know these techniques, I thought that I might be missing something. Maybe a usage of std::any or something else from c++20.

Answer (score 2):

There's a technique called "Immediately Invoked Lambda Expression" that is using lambda to initialize a variable in a complex way. Using this approach your `a` can be const which improves const-correctness. [More details here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html).

Answer (score 2):

For a simple binary predicate, consider just using the ternary operator:

```
struct A { int a; };

A initA(int a) { return A{a}; }
bool somePredicate(int input) { return input == 42; }

int main() {
    const auto input = 42;
    const auto a = somePredicate(input) ? initA(1) : initA(2);
}
```

for more complex initialization logic (beyond a binary case), wrap the initialization logic in a lambda:

```
struct A { int a; };

A initA(int a) { return A{a}; }
bool somePredicate(int input) { return input == 42; }

int main() {
    const auto input = 42;
    const auto a = []() { 
        if (somePredicate(input)) { return initA(1); }
        else if (input == 100) { return initA(100); }
        else { return initA(2); }}();
}
```

Both these approaches come with additional possibility of making the variable to be initialized `const`.

Comment: @Human-Compiler No it's fine, `input` is in scope here.

Answer (score 1):

If the return types of your lambda are different but convertible to some type then you can force the return type (note the `->` is mandatory when specifying a return type):

```
auto a = [=]() -> ConvertedType {
   if (some_predicate) {
      return CovertibleType1(1);
   } else if (other_predicate) {
      return ConvertibleType2(2);
   }
   return ConvertibleType3(3);
}();
```

Though I realize this basically defeats the `auto` declaration...